# Is there a prime element $\alpha=a+\sqrt{m} b$ such that $N(\alpha)|a$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

I have one question but first I will give some context:

For the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$ I consider the case where the ring of algebraic
integers is
$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})}=\mathbb{Z}[\omega_{m}]=\{a+\omega_{m}b\;|\;
a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ where $$\omega_{m}=\sqrt{m}.$$

Therefore for $\alpha=a+\omega_m b$, we have that the norm

$$N(\alpha):= \alpha\cdot\overline{\alpha}=a^{2}-mb^{2}$$

where $\overline{\alpha}=a-\omega_m b$ is the conjugate of $\alpha$

Now I am considering the quadratic imaginary case; i.e. $m<0$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\omega_{m}]$ is a PID.

If $\alpha=a+\omega_m b$ is a prime element in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega_{m}]$ such that $N(\alpha)=p$ is a prime number.

I know that $p$ can not divide $a$ and $b$ at the same time, otherwise from the definition of norm we have that

$$p=N(\alpha)= \alpha\cdot\overline{\alpha}=p\alpha\beta$$

for some $\beta\in\mathbb{Z}[\omega_{m}]$. It follows that $\alpha$ is a unit contradicting that is a prime element in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega_{m}]$.

So my question is the following: **Is it possible that $p$ divides only $a$?**.

I am thinking that the answer is no, since if $p$ divides $a$ we have that $N(\alpha)>p$ (since $m<0$ and therefore $a^{2}-mb^{2}$ is not negative)

With a similar argument we can answer negatively the question **Is it possible that $p$ divides only $b$?**

So I am confused about my reasoning, so any idea or correction it would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: This is not an answer, but: the ring of integers is not *always* as you stated. When the squarefree part of $m$ is $\equiv 1\mod{4}$, the ring of integers is larger. Also, you seem to say that for imaginary quadratic fields, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{m}]$ is a PID. That is not always the case either, even when $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{m}]$  is the full ring of integers.

Comment: If $p=a^2-mb^2$ and $p$ divides $a$ then $p\nmid b$ (as otherwise $p^2|a^2-mb^2$) so $p$ must divide $m$. If $m< 0$ then it must be that $m=-p$ (as otherwise $a^2-mb^2 > p$) and $b=\pm 1, a=0$.

Comment: Thank you, so only when $p$ is a prime congruent to $3$ mod $4$; i.e. the ring of integers is equal to $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-p}] $ we can have that $p$ divides $a$?